# Can't move icons to end of Card Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

We need to move the icons to the end of the Card and with a distance of 17px between them. I tried in different ways and align, but for some reason I can not move the icons to the end. I would be grateful if you tell me how to do it right.

```
Scrollbar(
          isAlwaysShown: true,
          thickness: 2,
          scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.left,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: close.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 9),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 47,
                child: Card(
                  color: constants.Colors.greyMiddle,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    bottom: 4,
                  ),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 9, vertical: 5),
                    child: Row(
                      // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        const CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: constants.Colors.white,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 11,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          close[index],
                          style: constants.Styles.smallerLtStdTextStyleWhite,
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            icon: SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.barPoynts)),
                        IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            icon: SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.crypto)),
                        IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                                constants.Assets.barFavourites)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

Comment: You just need to add a `Spacer()` widget  between the `Text()` and `IconButton()`. The Spacer widget will take up any available space. You might also want to add `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max` in your row so that it take max space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should wrap your `Text` widget with the `Expanded` widget, Which allocates the max-width to your Text so if your text gets bigger in length it will wrap it in a new line.

```dart
Expanded(
  child: Text(
    close[index],
    style: constants.Styles.smallerLtStdTextStyleWhite,
  ),
),
```

**Output:**

[image]

If you use only the `Spacer` widget as per the other answer (which will do the work) but if your text length got bigger it will result in an overflow error.

Like below:

[image]

Also Do not use `Spacer` and `Expanded` together, as Expanded's default flex and Spacer's default flex are set to `1`, flutter will allocate 'em equal amount of space and which will again cause an issue for you.

for example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. And if I wrapped the text in Expanded, but there is an invisible Padding around the icons that doesn't give the text enough space, is it possible to reduce the spacing in the icons themselves?

Comment: That is from the IconButton you are using, you can change `visualDensity` of the IconButton as per your need.

For example:

```dart
IconButton(
  visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
  onPressed: () {},
  icon: Icon(Icons.info),
),
```

This code will make it more compact.

Comment: Thank you. Can I still make the distance between the icons? Reduce, besides visualDensity ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try putting a Spacer() before the IconButtons. So like

```
                  children: [
                    const CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: constants.Colors.white,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 11,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      close[index],
                      style: constants.Styles.smallerLtStdTextStyleWhite,
                    ),
                    const Spacer(),
                    IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.barPoynts)),
                    IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: SvgPicture.asset(constants.Assets.crypto)),
                    IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                            constants.Assets.barFavourites)),
                  ],
```

Spacers always take as much space as they can

Answer (score 1):

```
{Text(close[index],
    style: constants.Styles.smallerLtStdTextStyleWhite,
                    ),}
```

After this, Write

```
Expanded(child:Container()),
```

And then icons. It will make space of container with empty area in Row.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).